# Case-insensitive language-to-iso code?

Tags: python

Is there a way to simplify the following:

```
>>> pycountry.languages.get(name='english')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pycountry/db.py", line 114, in get
    return self.indices[field][value]
KeyError: 'english'
>>> pycountry.languages.get(name='ENGLISH')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pycountry/db.py", line 114, in get
    return self.indices[field][value]
KeyError: 'ENGLISH'
>>> pycountry.languages.get(name='English')
<pycountry.db.Language object at 0x1096374d0>
```

In the above, 'English' is the only item that doesn't result in an Exception.

Comment: What are you asking?  If the last one with 'English' is the only one that works, then why can't you use it?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just use `name='enGLisH'.title()`?

Comment: @JoelHinz -- thanks, that's a good way to do it. I was thinking more in terms of SQL match but your way seems best for this module.